# onManagedUpdate never changes pSecondsElapsed - AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I have a Sprite, which is a ball, and it is falling properly, acording with my FixedStepPhysicsWorld options. But I would like a vector follow this ball as it is falling.
So I decided to override the onManagedUpdate sprite's method.

After lots of tests, I just got 1 vector drawn, then I realized that the pSecondsElapsed, were not being incremented.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {

         sPlayer= new Sprite(200,0, playerTextureRegion, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){

         @Override
         protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
             super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
             Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<<,>>>>>>>>>"+pSecondsElapsed+","");
         }
```

The output is the following:

```
11-07 21:14:32.242: D/<<<<<<<<<<<,>>>>>>>>0.02 (23720): [MainActivity.java:359:onManagedUpdate()] 
11-07 21:14:32.257: D/<<<<<<<<<<<,>>>>>>>>0.02 (23720): [MainActivity.java:359:onManagedUpdate()] 
11-07 21:14:32.281: D/<<<<<<<<<<<,>>>>>>>>0.02 (23720): [MainActivity.java:359:onManagedUpdate()]
```

My Engine is like:

```
  @Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(final EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
return new FixedStepEngine(pEngineOptions, 50);
}
```

QUESTION:
1 - Why pSecondsElapsed is not changing?
2 - I want to draw vectors for each position of this ball. Should I detach and atach a new Line each time this method(onManagedUpdate) is called?

Comment: that variable is the time since last tick so it should be constant. but onManagedUpdate is called per tick so your code should still work as needed.

Comment: @kabuto178 Is it not possible it be incremented?

Comment: You should make something like -> int sec = 0; sec+=pSecondsElapsed; and the use this "sec" instead of pSecondsElapsed.

Comment: As Shaq suggested, you could create a field variable as a counter, but what ever code you use in the `OnManagedUpdate()` will be executed as needed per tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API tried to make that clear by calling it "Seconds Elapsed" which means "seconds passed" since the last time the update was called. It's not a cumulative number, but instead the number of milliseconds since the function was last called.

If you want to maintain a cumulative count, you will need to add pSecondsElapsed to a counter variable on each call of that function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason pSecondsElapsed is not changing is due to two conditions being true.
1) You are using a FixedStepOption with the frame rate set to 50.
2) The android you tested it on had the capability to run at 50 frames per second.

This results in it running 50 FPS which results in .02 of a second elapsed per frame.  (1 second divided by 50 frames).  You can test this by changing the 50 to 25 and expect to get .04 (1 second divided by 25 frames).

Where it becomes important is if the hardware cannot support the frame rate you specify.  In this case, it is likely it varies due to needing to do more work in certain situations of your app.  (For example if you create an explosion the FPS may drop due to the extra sprites).

To properly support hardware that cannot keep up with the framerate you specify, you can use the pSecondsElapsed to account for the variance.  (for example by multiplying the distance times the variance in elapsed time vs specified time).